# SHA Hash function C vs java

Tags: java, c, hash

I am reading [this paper](https://www.cdc.informatik.tu-darmstadt.de/reports/reports/BDKOV07.pdf) and at the beginning of the page 12 say:

> we use the ratio cHash  = cPrng = 0.002 ms, which we obtained using a Java implementation of SHA1 on a Pentium dualcore 1.8GHz.

Here cHash is the cost of one application of the hash function SHA. My question is: Is it possible? someone have verified that? Using Linux, gcc and the SHA1 of the library openssl/sha.h (on input {0x61,0x62,0x63}) I get 0.002s and using java I get on average 0.088s

```
import java.security.MessageDigest;
public class test_SHA_java 
{
public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception
{
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
String text = "This is some text";

md.update(text.getBytes("UTF-8")); // Change this to "UTF-16" if needed
byte[] digest = md.digest();
 }
}
real    0m0.087s
user    0m0.080s
sys 0m0.022s
```

Here is the C code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <openssl/sha.h>
void hashc(void *src, size_t slen)
{
    unsigned char md1[SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    SHA1(src, slen, md1);
}

int main()
{
    unsigned char data[] = {0x61,0x62,0x63}; // "abc"
    hashc(data, SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH);
    return 0;
}

real    0m0.002s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.001s
```

Comment: Given that a good GPU based hash engine can calculate SHA1 hashes on a billions per second scale, 0.002s sounds very slow to me. Even `hashcat` (the non-GPU version) can do millions of hashes using a single thread.

Comment: @JohnKugelman Not on a single CPU, in fact not even on a CPU but on multiple GPUs. A single CPU will be several orders of magnitude slower, but not a million times slower, that doesn't sound realistic. The 0.002ms/hash (or 500k hash/s) value sounds about right.

Comment: @biziclop do you know which is the best hash implementaion of SHA family in C?

Comment: No, I'm not up to date with C libraries. But I think you should create a more realistic micro-benchmark, the time of running the hash just once will be dominated by the time it takes to start/exit the program.

Comment: When you compute hashing only once, and wit so small time interval, you will see huge errors, related to OS start your program, program initialize some pre-main data, etc. for correct computing, I suggest you modify program and run each hashing many times, for example - 10,000. Thus, percentage of "pure hashing time" will be much more in "total program run time", and you will receive more accurate values.